# W3C compliant struts tags

Tags: html, struts, w3c

I have a web page(.jsp) created using struts tag libraries. when I try to validate the web page in w3c.org, all the struts tags are coming up as undefined. E.g `<html:button>` is undefined . The DOCTYPE I have used is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue. Or can't we make a struts based web page as W3C compliant.

Answer (score 0):

...

Why are you trying to validate a page *before rendering*?

Are Struts tags (or *any* other custom tag) valid HTML tags? Of course not.

Validation should occur *after* the page is rendered.